# html:Is there a way to include scrollbar for html code

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have to include a scrollbar for my html code below.Code goes like-->

```
 <html>
   <head></head>
      <body>
<div style="overflow:scroll;height:100px;scrollbar-shadow-color: #2D2C4D;scrollbar-highlight-color:#7D7E94;scrollbar-face-color: #000000;scrollbar-3dlight-color:#7D7E94;">
         <table width="100%" style="border-collapse:collapse;overflow:scroll;height:10px">
    <tr>
         <% dim CountFlg
                CountFlg = 0
                for i=0 to XmlNodes.length-1
                    if CountFlg <= 2 then %>
                        <td>
                            <b><%=XmlNodes.item(i).getAttribute("xx")%></b>                                
                        </td>
                        <TD>
                            <input class="TextArea" name="<% xx % >" id="<% xx %>" style="height:35px;overflow:auto;padding-left:80px;" rows="5"cols="10"> </input>
                        </TD>
                        <% CountFlg=CountFlg+1
                    end if
                next%>
            </tr>
           </table>
          </div>
         </body>
        </html>
```

Since I have a for loop here I don't know how many  tags I'll get.So I thought of putting a scrollbar for my  tag.How to do this?Is there a way I can put if conition for div tag here,like if XmlNodes.length>8 then include div tag else no need of div tag.How to do this.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must enclose your table in a `div`, and make that div `overflow:scroll` , like this:

```
<div style="overflow:scroll; height:300px">
   <table>  // your table
   </table> // goes here
</div>
```

Comment: :Thanks for the answer.It worked.But right-side scrollbar is invisible.How to do this?

Comment: :I have to do another thing here,i have to include div only if "XmlNodes.length">8.How to do this?plz suggext an answer.

Comment: it works fine for me, can you made a testcase of your problem in http://jsfiddle.net ? so I can reproduce your problem.

Comment: :Okay that i`ll check and let you know.I have changed my post again.I have to put if condition for div tag.how to do this?Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

using CSS:

```
<table style="overflow:scroll, height:200px">
```

If I remembered my CSS right, that should cause a scroll bar to appear on the table element if you have more than 200px worth of content.  Note that you have to fix the height, otherwise the element will just keep on growing (and therefor have no overflow to scroll)

Comment: the character to separate css properties is ; not comma.

Comment: @logical Chimp:I have tried the style tag you mentioned,that didn`t work.I have changed my table tag please check.

Answer (score 0):

IF i want only height wise scroll then what to do? Currently I am getting row wise and column wise scroll. If know how to do then please let me know.

Lots of Thank you in advance.

--- HERE I get the solutions

overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: scroll; works !!

Answer (score 0):

you can use overflow property of css

```
overflow-x
overflow-y
overflow
```